# Using recursion to combine values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I have a dictionary containing lists of varying lengths and I would like a general algorithm to produce the combinations of all the elements within the lists. A piece of example code is given below:

```
bob = {'a':['a','b','c'],     
   'b':[0],
   'c':['x','y']}


for i in bob['a']:
    for j in bob['b']:
        for k in bob['c']:
            print("%s - %s - %s"%(str(i),str(j),str(k)))
```

This is the desired output for the particular dictionary 'bob' and it produces the output:

```
a - 0 - x
a - 0 - y
b - 0 - x
b - 0 - y
c - 0 - x
c - 0 - y
```

However, I would like a general algorithm. Could I use recursion to generalise this so it can handle dictionaries with an arbitrary number of keys, if so how?

Extra Info: The values corresponding to the keys will always be 1D lists

Comment: Have you tried to come up with your own solution?

Comment: To answer your immediate question, yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general algorithm is [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> print(*itertools.product(*bob.values()), sep='\n')
('a', 0, 'x')
('a', 0, 'y')
('b', 0, 'x')
('b', 0, 'y')
('c', 0, 'x')
('c', 0, 'y')
```

Comment: This is not very efficient memory-wise because it expands the full product into a tuple instead of using the fact that it is a generator.

Comment: `deque(map(print, itertools.product(*bob.values())), maxlen=0)`

Comment: Use plain old for-loops if you want lazyness / memory efficiency.  deque-map-print is needless obfuscation.

Comment: Of course it is. It's the "obligatory one-liner" :)

Answer (score 3):

Use product from itertools, it's very handy:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for x in product(*[bob[k] for k in ('a', 'b', 'c')]):
...     print(' - '.join(map(str, x)))
...
a - 0 - x
a - 0 - y
b - 0 - x
b - 0 - y
c - 0 - x
c - 0 - y
```

if the order of `bob`'s keys is not relevant, you can simplify this to:

```
>>> for x in product(*bob.values()):
...     print(' - '.join(map(str, x)))
```